# How to increase limit of sending in Symfony 4 mailer

Tags: php, symfony, email, mailer

I have a problem or question with sending emails by Symfony mailer - https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/mailer.html (not SwiftMailer https://symfony.com/doc/4.4/email.html)

I create simple code to find persons witch non active membership and send email to them. This task is scheduled in crontab to run every day at 09:55 and this works perfect. Each send try are logged at database, and i can count amount of sent emails.

And now I have a problem with something like queue i think in Symfony, because i have logs from email, and I see this:
[image: Problem with queue at sending email]
In this case 73 mails are sent, but only exact 10 mails was sent instantly, and rest 63 mails was sent exact after 30 minutes.

I would like to configure Symfony mailer to send all mails instantly or 10 mails in 1 minutes (but without 30 minutes delay).

Symfony and Symfony/mailer in version 4.4.19 and my config file is here

```
#/config/packages/mailer.yaml
framework:
    mailer:
        dsn: '%env(MAILER_DSN)%'


#.env
MAILER_DSN=smtp://AAA@AAA.com:BBB@CCC:587
```

Thank's for any advices.

EDIT:
This is my CronController

```
<?php
/**
 * Cron controller.
 */

namespace App\Controller;

use App\Service\MembershipService;
use App\Service\LogService;
use App\Service\MailService;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Annotation\Route;

/**
 * Class CronController.
 *
 * @Route("/cron")
 */
class CronController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * Send emails for not payed memberships.
     *
     * @param MembershipService $membershipService Membership service
     * @param MailService       $mailService       Mail service
     * @param LogService        $logService        Log service
     *
     * @return jsonResponse JSON response with counter of sent email
     *
     * @Route(
     *     "/sendReminders/",
     *     name="cron_sendReminders",
     *     methods={"GET"},
     * )
     */
    public function sendReminders(DonationService $donationService, MailService $mailService, LogService $logService): JsonResponse
    {
        //Declare counter
        $counter = 0;
        //Get all not payed memberships from 1 days
        $memberships = $membershipService->getNotPayedMemberships();
        //Foreach membership send email
        foreach ($memberships as $membership) {
            //If sent email
            if ($mailService->sendRemindMail($membership['memberName'], $membership['memberEmail'], $membership['paymentSessionId'])) {
                //Save log about that
                $logService->addNewLog($membership['memberEmail'], 11, 'Sent email.');
                //Mark membership as notified
                $donationService->setNotifiedDonation($membership['membershipId']);
                //Increase counter
                ++$counter;
            }
        }

        return JsonResponse::create(['count' => $counter]);
    }
}
```

And i call this controller in crontab by

```
55 09 * * * /usr/local/bin/curl --silent https://MYSERVER.DOMAIN/cron/sendReminders/ >/dev/null
```

This controller use function sendRemindMail in MailService and this is the code:

```
/**
 * Sending reminder message.
 *
 * @param string $receiverName  Receiver name
 * @param string $receiverEmail Receiver mail
 * @param string $paymentLink   Generated link
 *
 * @return bool Status of send
 */
public function sendRemindMail(string $receiverName, string $receiverEmail, string $paymentLink): bool
{
    $email = (new TemplatedEmail())
        ->from(new Address($this->params->getParameter('smtpMail'), $this->params->getParameter('smtpSender')))
        ->to($receiverEmail)
        ->subject($this->params->getParameter('smtpSender').' - '.$this->translator->trans('Donation_not_payed'))
        ->htmlTemplate('emails/remind.html.twig')
        ->context([
            'receiverName' => $receiverName,
            'paymentLink' => $this->params->getParameter('appLink').'summary/'.$paymentLink
        ]);
    try {
        $this->mailer->send($email);

        return true;
    } catch (TransportExceptionInterface $e) {
        $this->logs->addNewLog('mailservice@system', 82, 'Error during send email (sendRemindMail)');

        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which mailer are you using and does that mailer have a queue system implemented to prevent spamming? Maybe you need a verified / paid account to send more emails per X-period?

Comment: Example: https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/faqs.html#why-not-just-use-sendmail-postfix-courier-imap

Comment: @rkeet I use my own SMTP server with own domain. There isn't any limitation, because llibraries works with clear PHP (PHPMailer) can send over 200 emails instatly.

Screen comes from DirectAdmin panel on my own VPS at OVH.

Comment: What command is called in your cronjob? If its a custom command, can you show the code for sending the mail. Are you using the Messenger-integration for the Mailer-component?

Comment: @dbrumann I update my question and add code of controller and service to send. I am not using Messenger-integration. I use templated email to send emails via Mailer-component.

Comment: Do you see any errors from your catch-block in your logs?

Comment: @dbrumann No, only custom success logs in DB.

Is this Mailer-component have queue similar to SwiftMailler (https://symfony.com/doc/4.2/email/spool.html)?